# searching for clouds (in the sky) images big dataset

Tags: data-request, geospatial, images

I'm looking for a big dataset of clouds (in the sky) ground based images. i need tens of thousands of images.

It is important that the images will be ground based and not from satellite/ flights.

I've tried to search and so far found datasets of hundreds/thousands of images, but not the amount I need.

I'll appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### [Multimodal Vision Research Laboratory](http://mvrl.cs.uky.edu/data/)

Below is a list of datasets that are made publicly available for research purposes.

```
Archive of Many Outdoor Scenes (AMOS): A dataset containing hundreds of millions of images gathered from publicly available outdoor webcams.
Crossview USA (CVUSA): A large dataset containing millions of pairs of ground-level and aerial/satellite images from across the United States.
Face2Year: A large number of images extracted from highschool yearbooks.
GeoFaces: A dataset containing millions of geotagged images of human faces.
Horizon Lines in the Wild: A large dataset of images annotated with horizon lines.
LOST: A large dataset containing streaming video collected from publicly available outdoor webcams.
SkyFinder: A large dataset of webcam images annotated with sky regions.
Timelapse Clouds: A dataset containing videos of clouds and cloud shadows captured by stationary ground-based cameras.
```

#### [SkyFinder](http://mvrl.cs.uky.edu/datasets/skyfinder/)

**Dataset Description**

A large dataset of webcam images annotated with sky regions.

#### [Archive of Many Outdoor Scenes (AMOS)](http://mvrl.cs.uky.edu/datasets/amos/)

**Dataset Description**

A dataset containing hundreds of millions of images gathered from publicly available outdoor webcams.

Answer (score 0):

The [Crowdsource](https://crowdsource.google.com) dataset has candid pictures of the sky, taken by ordinary people from the ground, often including other landscape elements:

https://crowdsource.google.com/images?labels=cloud
https://crowdsource.google.com/images?labels=sky

Right now there are not many, but there is currently a campaign to capture vastly more sky pictures, so I believe their number should increase dramatically next time the database is updated.

Disclaimer: I work for Crowdsource.